# Explain the length and clear session store methods in connect session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, store

The express session [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/session) says that the `.length(callback)` and `.clear(callback)` methods may be implemented in a custom implementation of a session store.

But are these methods supposed to do? Is it "*give the number of registered sessions*" and "*delete all existing sessions*"?

Comment: I believe those methods refer, just as the ones that must be implemented, to the current session. Length should return the number of session objects set, and clear should remove all. If you are familiar with PHP they would be somewhat similar to `count($_SESSION)` and `unset $_SESSION;`. Although someone with more experience on the subject might prove this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`Mongo Session`](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/master/lib/connect-mongo.js), it seems that you're correct on both counts.  `.length` returns the number of sessions, while `.clear` clears **all** data:

```
/**
 * Fetch number of sessions.
 *
 * @param {Function} callback
 * @api public
 */

 MongoStore.prototype.length = function(callback) {
    // code
  };

  /**
   * Clear all sessions.
   *
   * @param {Function} callback
   * @api public
   */

  MongoStore.prototype.clear = function(callback) {
    // code
  };
```